# WKT from current map view in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

Trying to find the best way to take the current map view extent

```
const extent = mapView.calculateExtent();
```

and get a WKT from that value. i thought i might be able to take that extent, convert it into a polygon:

```
const poly =  fromExtent(mapExt);
```

and then somehow get the geometry from that polygon and convert to wkt like so:

```
const wktFormat = new WKT();
const polyGeom = //get geometry from poly here?
const ret = wktFormat.writeGeometry(polyGeom, {
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```

but i'm not able to find a good way to do that.  Am i missing a step?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988453/how-to-get-the-current-viewport-of-the-map-out-of-openlayers-as-geometry-boundi

Comment: that link doesn't help.  It only says to use mapView.calculateExtent(), which i already show i'm using above.  I have the extent, i need to either a) find a way to convert extent into a geometry, or b) find a way to translate an extent into WKT.  Either one is fine for me.  There was a comment in your link about using .ToGeometry().ToString(), but that method doesn't exist in OL 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your extent to a polygon using `ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent()`.

You can try something like this:

```
var e = map.getView().calculateExtent();
var wkt = format.writeGeometry(ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(e), {
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
console.log(wkt);
```

Comment: thanks, i was getting hung up apparently cause i thought i had to run getGeometry on the polygon